# Netbeans would not find compatible jdk while installation

Tags: java, netbeans

Netbeans would not find compatible jdk while installation while JDKs are located at `C:Java` and the files are:

- jdk-8u73-windows-i586
- jdk-8u73-windows-x64
- jdk-8u141-windows-i586

Comment: Please, consider edit your question adding some details (what NetBeans version are you using, the exact error message you get, ...)

You probably won't receive any answer otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [NetBeans Installation Instructions](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/73/install.html)

> The default location in Windows is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10 or similar.

If your JDK is at `C:\Java` you just have to:

- re-install the JDK under the default Netbeans location, *or*
- specify your custom location during the installation wizard

Comment: thanks specified the location for sdks while installation also changed path to C:\Program Files\Java\ now the error is "An unknown error occured while validating the path" added sdks to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73 still error

Comment: Please, just copy-paste your error message on a search engine before posting here. For instance, you could take a look here: https://forums.netbeans.org/post-162599.html#162599

Answer (score 0):

Since I've run into this problem and this Q/A came up in my search, here is the solution that I found worked for me on the Windows platform.

I had to set up an system environmental variable named JAVA_HOME that pointed to the JDK directory.

```
JAVA_HOME=D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
```

Even after this change, I still ran into the "An unknown error occured while validating path."

Right-click on the NetBeans install software and select "Run as Administrator...".  It looks like running the installer under your normal account, even though it may have admin rights, is not enough to scan the "\Program Files" folder and find the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

*Delete your old java files.

*Download jdk file from.
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

*install new jdk version.

*Then install NetBeans //Now it will automatically identify your jdk and no need for manual selection...